# Saving all layer edits at once in QGIS

Tags: qgis, layers, editing, save

Is there a way to save all layer edits at once (preferably with a shortcut)?

This would be very handy to easily save and protect layer edits routinely in the event of a crash.

I often find QGIS crashing (for various reasons) and it's heartbreaking when all my layer edits were not saved.

Answer (score 4):

Under the `Digitizing Toolbar`, there is an option to save edits for all layers.

[image]

It will be active once you edit a feature or features of any layer loaded in the project.

If the Digitizing Toolbar is not shown in the project, you can activate it from `View → Toolbars → Digitizing Toolbar`, or easier, right-click any place in the `Toolbars` under the `Menu Toolbar` and select the `Digitizing Toolbar`.